# How to create a StackTrace logic for a call that goes through different micro service using gRPC exchanges

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, microservices, stack-trace, grpc

I created 4 microservices in Go in order to form myself to the microservices architecture and go.

However, I am afraid that I am gonna face some issues which are the handling of the errors.

Even if I tried to put checks as much as I could to verify that I have no errors in my data at runetime, if it does crash, I would like a stack trace of the error but I am not sure about how I should integrate it.. Also, the first time I will run my microservices altogether, if I have a weird behavior, such as an add that doesn't work, or an update, a get, whatever in one of my microservice, of course I will know from which microservice it will come from, but how will I be able to get to know it fast if I have no trace?

I already have some ideas, but I want to create something as much generic as I can. I saw `pkg/errors` but I am not sure how will it works throughout my different microservices...

Since I use `Protobuf`and `gRPC` exchanges, I know I will need to pass the stackTrace throughout messages, however, I need to map this stacktrace through each microservice I pass.. So it's a lot of redundant code

Maybe I am wrong, but what did I do is I created one proto file by microservice, so the objects (structs definitions) aren't the same, doesn't it?

I had this idea:

```
message Status {
    uint32 Code = 1;
    string Service = 2;
    string Method = 3;
    string Message = 4;
    Status InnerStatus = 5;
}
```

So, I get the code, the service name, the method name, a message "box", and a spot to put a sub level of tracing. However, if I want to put two trace at the same level, the logic is broken.